# Swift - append works erratically

Tags: swift

I have an issue when using append, it seems very simple but I cannot find an explanation, I created a simple example to explain things simply.
I declared a class called Customer, like this:

```
    class Customer {
        var id: Int = 0
        var name: String = ""
        var latitude: Double = 0
        var longitud: Double = 0
        var image: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "restaurantImage")
    }
```

I initialised an empty array (global for the moment)

```
var customerList = [Customer]()
```

Then I have a function like this:

```
func createCustomerList () {
    let customer = Customer()
    customer.id = 1
    customer.name = "Restaurant 1"
    customer.latitude = 0.13
    customer.longitud = 0.14
    customer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "restaurantImage1")

    customerList.append(customer)

    customer.id = 2
    customer.name = "Restaurant 2"
    customer.latitude = 0.15
    customer.longitud = 0.16
    customer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "restaurantImage2")

    customerList.append(customer)
}
```

I'm trying to use the same constant to create two different elements in the "customerList" array.
When I check the array, it contains two elements but the two are the same (the latest), it happens if I make it 10 times and also if I declare the "Customer" element as a var.
Can someone help me....?

This is a silly code, but would help me solve a real issue in my project...

Comment: You need to create a second instance of your Customer class

Comment: Classes are reference types.  That means when you change `customer` after pushing it the first time, you're actually just changing the same one and then adding a second reference to it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's check what you code does.

```
let customer = Customer()
```

Good you have created a new instance of `Customer`.

```
customer.id = 1
customer.name = "Restaurant 1"
customer.latitude = 0.13
customer.longitud = 0.14
customer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "restaurantImage1")
```

You go about setting the necessary values and append it. So now the array contains this customer.

Now what you do next is the problem. You are using the same `Customer` instance and changing his information.

```
customer.id = 2
customer.name = "Restaurant 2"
customer.latitude = 0.15
customer.longitud = 0.16
customer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "restaurantImage2")
```

This is reflected in both the array and let `customer` instance, because the array contains a reference to your `customer`. So when you append it again, the latest version is added while the first one is updated.

**SOLUTION**

If you want another customer to be be appended you should create another instance

```
let customer2 = Customer()

//Change customer2 parameters

customerList.append(customer2)
```

or you could change the declaration to a variable and store a new instance to it.

```
var customer = Customer() 

//Change customer details

customerList.append(customer)

customer = Customer() // New customer instance

//Change customer details

customerList.append(customer)
```